# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/operation/OperationExecutor

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, maven

I already had mongodb java driver and maven. I cannot find out where the probelm is. Anyone can help, thank you?

The eclipse IDE always show this error, even I didnot do any insert,find functions:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/mongodb/operation/OperationExecutor The detail reason is showing
>   this:   MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( DB_HOST , 27017 );

Comment: You are missing mongodb driver dependency at runtime

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant parts of your `pom.xml` to show how you are configured.

Comment: Be sure that eclipse is configured to add mongodb in the classpath before compilation. If you use maven i think you build with run as > maven build ?